# Long term stability of 1602 LCD contrast calibration?

Tags: lcd, character-lcd

When setting the contrast on a 1602 or similar LCD module such as [this one](https://www.auscomtech.com.au/product/1602-16x2-lcd-display-iic-i2c-twi-spi-serial-interface-module-for-arduino/) does the contrast remain relatively constant over the lifetime of the display or would it require periodic recalibration as the LCD slowly fades over it's?

I am considering using something like this in my application - the user would only need to read it once in a blue moon (providing WIFI IP address to access devices controls using a mobile device) but if the product needs to be opened up every year for maintenance just to calibrate the display then obviously this is not a solution.

Comment: They stay relatively consistent.  When I've had to adjust, its been due to something else aging - usually related to the power supply.  One on a very good, appropriately over-specd (and under used) system has not required adjustment since I set it ~5 years ago.

Comment: @Abel - Hi, Thanks for your comment. As it says in the comment box "Avoid answering questions in comments" and IMHO your useful comment would be much better as an answer, as it is an answer to the question :-) Also, the OP cannot accept a comment which answers the question, and you can't update it if more clarification is requested etc. etc. So would you please move your comment into an answer (& delete the comment)? Thanks :-)

Comment: @norlesh, what is your lcd's power source?

Comment: Will be powered by a 5V stepped down regulator (from 36V DC)